# Hide/Show button Nav onClick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I'm trying to hide the Open navigation button onClick, when the side navigation opens.
When I click the openNav button, I want the button to hide, and when I closeNav, the button should show up.

I have looked at similar questions, but I haven't found something that worked.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<button class="pull-right btnstyle" onclick="openNav()">&times;</button>
<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/748fhbkw/2/

```js
 openNav = function() {
  $('button[id="openModal"]').hide();
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  
}

closeNav = function() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  $('button[id="openModal"]').show();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<button id="openModal" class="pull-right btnstyle" onclick="openNav()">&times;</button>
<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try using .

document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the button when you are opening the menu and show it when you are closing the menu.

```js
function openNav(open) {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  open.style.display = 'none'; //it will hide the element that is passed in the function parameter
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById('openButton').style.display = 'block'; //it will show the button that is used to open the menu 
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <a href="#">About</a>
 <a href="#">Services</a>
 <a href="#">Clients</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<button class="pull-right btnstyle" id="openButton" onclick="openNav(this)">&times;</button>
<div id="main">
 <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
 <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added `document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";` to your `openNav()` and inverted it for the `closeNav()`. Same for the open/closing-button.

I've also added `style="display: none;"` as default to the menu, so the menu is not shown at the start.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block"; // This one to show the menu
  document.getElementById("openmenu").style.display = "none"; // and hide the "Open Menu"-Button
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none"; // This one to hide the menu
  document.getElementById("openmenu").style.display = "block"; // and show the "Open Menu"-Button
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="display: none;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">Close Menu</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<button class="pull-right btnstyle" id="openmenu" onclick="openNav()">Open Menu</button>
<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```